# Is it possible to resize the temp event added with selectMirror in FullCalendar v5.7.2?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I managed to get a *temporary* event making use of [selectMirror](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectMirror) in FullCalendar v5.7.2.

I was wondering if there is a way to dynamically resize this event based on user preference. I tried to access the last element of the `calendar.getEvents()` but this returned an already validated event.

Any feedback would be very useful for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I managed to get a temporary event

...it's not really a temporary event, it's just showing you the currently [selected](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting) area in a more emphatic way than the default display. (The documentation calls it a "placeholder event" but that's a bit of a misnomer really compared to its actual functionality.) Therefore none of the event-related functions are any use to you here.

The easiest way to resize it is simply for the user to go back and drag again to select a different area. However if you want to do it programmatically based on some other input from the user (e.g. via a separate datepicker control, or something like that) then you can use the `select()` function to change the current selection, e.g.

```
calendar.select(start, end)
```

where `start` and `end` are valid Date objects or date-parseable strings.

More info: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-select